# How can I take a word as a input from a web page by double clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I want to build an web application that needs to take a word as a input from the web page by double clicking on it. I know it is possible because I’ve seen this mechanism in E2B dictionary in Google chrome extension.
this application website link-

[E2B dictionary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bangla-dictionary-e2b-onl/kdofmbkpgbcabbjdaomfjhgplpbbgohi)

But, I don’t know how they have done it. I searched it google much but get no useful information. So, specifically is there any API or library function in JavaScript which can do this.  If there is no such library function in JavaScript so then how they can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script uses [window#getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) with [document#execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) and works in chrome, firefox and edge:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var body = document.querySelector('body');

demo.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
  var s = window.getSelection();
  var w = s.focusNode.data.substring(s.anchorOffset, s.focusOffset).trim();
  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  body.appendChild(inp)
  inp.value = w;
  inp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy', false);
  inp.remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis mi et eleifend tristique. Fusce tincidunt interdum augue, vel tincidunt quam accumsan a. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam congue urna in mauris varius posuere. Vivamus sit amet magna
  purus. Suspendisse convallis porttitor elit, quis ultricies enim consectetur id. Vestibulum justo ligula, mattis ut eleifend eu, varius egestas nisl. Donec porta eros sodales nunc mollis, vel hendrerit magna semper. Phasellus convallis bibendum turpis.
  Praesent nisl risus, dictum sed luctus id, aliquam laoreet libero. In ac auctor nibh. Pellentesque mattis, quam sit amet mollis tincidunt, est leo fermentum elit, eget pretium urna elit id metus. Sed id tellus id nisi venenatis dignissim.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

chrome extension can take original web page contents (already loaded in browser) and add own functionality to it (scripts/style/modify dom). in this case you may want split all the texts by words and wrap them to several span-like html tags with attached click events to show some tooltips.